# Meteor Event handler on child input inside a div

Tags: jquery, events, meteor

I have this html structure.

```
<div class="test">
 <input type="text" /> <!-- this input is generated autoamitcally so i cant set id or className -->
</div>
```

Now i want to use the keypress event inside the input, how my `eventtype selector` should look?

Already try with

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
 'keypress .test.input .test input':function(event,template){
   console.log("and work"); //this dosnt get printed on the console.
 }
})
```

I know 'keypress input' works but i have another inputs on the same template, so i want to just trigger the keypress on this input.

Answer (score 2):

For an autogenerated input, use standard jquery event in Templates.sometemplate.rendered. For instance, this code will fire an event everytime I press a key inside the answerbox at SO:

```
$('.wmd-container').find('textarea').on('keypress', function(){
  console.log('i r texted')
})
```

In your case, wmd-container can be any parent div

Answer (score 1):

If you have other inputs (besides the one which will be automatically generated) in the .test div and none of them has an ID nor CLASS there is no way to know which input dispatched the event. You have to use unique id, class or name parameters on each input field.

On the other hand if you have only that one input inside the .test div then the event you are looking for should be `'keypress .test input'`
See this MeteorPad for example: [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/b2kusMrqvBkJwk8AC/Meteor%20Event%20handler%20on%20child%20input%20inside%20a%20div)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'keypress .test input[type="text"]': function(event,template) {
    console.log("and work", event.target);
  }
});
```

Just learn about CSS selectors: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048